# mysql repartitioned table much larger

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I have a very large table on a mysql 5.6.10 instance (roughly 480 million rows).
The storage engine is InnoDB. (Table and DB Default).
The table was partitioned by hash of merchantId (bigint: a kind of client identifier) which helped when queries related to a single merchant.  Due to significant performance degradation when queries spanned multiple merchants, I decided to repartition the table by Range on ACTION_DATE (the DATE that an activity occurred).  Thinking I was being clever, I decided to add a few (5) new fields for future use (unused_varchar1 varchar(200), etc.), since the table is so large, adding new fields essentially requires a rebuild anyway, so why not...

I created the new table structure as _new, dumped the existing file to a secondary server using mysql dump.  I then used an awk script to finesse the name and a few other details to fit the new table  (change tableName to tableName_new), and started the load.

The existing table was approximately 430 GB.  The text file similarly was about 403 GB.  I was surprised therefore that the new table ended up taking about 840 GB!!  (Based on the linux fize size of the .ibd files)

So, I have 2 basic questions, which really amount to why and what now...

I imagine that the new table is larger because the dump file was in the order of the previous partition (merchantId) while the load was inserting into the new partitioning (Activity date) creating a semi-random insertion order.  The randomness led mysql to leave plenty of space (roughly 50%) in the pages for future insertions. (I'm a little fuzzy on the terminology here, having spent much more time in my career with Sql Server DBs than MySql Dbs...)  I'm not able to find any internal statistics in mysql for space free per page.  The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES DATA_FREE stat is an unconvincing 68MB.

If it helps these are the relevant stats from I_S.TABLES:

TABLE_TYPE:   BASE TABLE
Engine:       InnoDB
VERSION:      10
ROW_FORMAT:   Compact
TABLE_ROWS:     488,094,271
AVG_ROW_LENGTH:       1,564
DATA_LENGTH:    763,509,358,592 (711 GB)
INDEX_LENGTH:   100,065,574,912 (93.19 GB) 
DATA_FREE:        68,157,440 (0.06 GB)

I realize that that doesn't add up to 840 GB, but as I said, that was the size of the .ibd files which seems to be slightly different than the I_S.TABLES stats.  Either way, it is significantly more than the text dump file.
I digress...

My question is whether my theory about whether the repartioning explains the roughly doubled size.  Or is there another explanation?  I think the extra columns (2 Bigint, 2 Varchar(200), 1 Date) are not the culprit since they are all null.  My napkin calculation was that the additional columns would add < 9 GB.  Likewise, one additional index on UID should be a relatively small addition.

The follow up question is what can I do now if I want to try to compact the table.  (Server now only has about 385 GB free...)
If I repeated the procedure, dump to file, reload, this time in the current partition order, would I end up with a table more like the size of my original table ~430 GB?

Following are relevant parts of DDL.

OLD TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  `AUTO_SEQ` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `MERCHANT_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `AFFILIATE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROGRAM_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ACTION_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `UID` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
... additional columns ... 
  PRIMARY KEY (`AUTO_SEQ`,`MERCHANT_ID`,`PROGRAM_ID`),
  KEY `oc_rpt_mpad_idx` (`MERCHANT_ID`,`PROGRAM_ID`,`ACTION_DATE`,`AFFILIATE_ID`),
  KEY `oc_rpt_mapd` (`MERCHANT_ID`,`ACTION_DATE`),
  KEY `oc_rpt_apda_idx` (`AFFILIATE_ID`,`PROGRAM_ID`,`ACTION_DATE`,`MERCHANT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (merchant_id)
PARTITIONS 16 */
```

NEW TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName_new` (
  `AUTO_SEQ` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `MERCHANT_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `AFFILIATE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROGRAM_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ACTION_DATE` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `UID` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
... additional columns...
# NEW COLUMNS (ALL NULL)
  `UNUSED_BIGINT1` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNUSED_BIGINT2` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNUSED_VARCHAR1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNUSED_VARCHAR2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNUSED_DATE1` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AUTO_SEQ`,`ACTION_DATE`),
  KEY `oc_rpt_mpad_idx` (`MERCHANT_ID`,`PROGRAM_ID`,`ACTION_DATE`,`AFFILIATE_ID`),
  KEY `oc_rpt_mapd` (`ACTION_DATE`),
  KEY `oc_rpt_apda_idx` (`AFFILIATE_ID`,`PROGRAM_ID`,`ACTION_DATE`,`MERCHANT_ID`),
  KEY `oc_uid` (`UID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(ACTION_DATE)
(PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p05 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p06 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p07 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p08 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p09 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p17 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p19 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p21 VALUES LESS THAN ('2017-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN ('2017-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p23 VALUES LESS THAN ('2017-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN ('2017-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p25 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p26 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p27 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p28 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p29 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Comment: You might get more help with this question on **dba.stackexchange.com**.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the added columns at the end of the row to contribute significantly towards the row size, since they have NULL values, and InnoDB doesn't use MyISAM-style FIXED format rows. I'm assuming that you've compared the InnoDB row format of the old and new tables, and the old table wasn't using row format `COMPRESSED`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at asking the same question there.  The old table was using the same row format as far as I know.  I'm more interested in whether random insertion vs. the partition (ACTION_DATE) would lead to wasted space / half empty pages.  I wouldn't expect it to, but then I didn't expect the table to be twice the size of its text file either.

Comment: You could try a rebuild on just one partition, and compare the size of the new .ibd file with the size of the current ibd file (obviously, you need to capture the current size, before the rebuild. `ALTER TABLE mytable REBUILD PARTITION p13;` (It kinda goes without saying here... obviously, we're assuming that you've got the `innodb_file_per_table`  set, you're not talking about the size of the shared table space.)

Comment: I didn't realize I could do that!  I will give it a try on one of the older partitions and see what happens.  Yes, we are using innodb_file_per_table, so the files in question are related only to this particular table.

Comment: the REBUILD works on a per partition,  that's going to effectively "copy" the old partition into a new one. The table will be locked while that happens. BUT... *beware* of the REORGANIZE partition... that seems like it should work on just one partition, but it does *all* the partitions. (Notes about that are in the MySQL Reference Manual under the "partitioning" section.) I'm curious whether the partition rebuild results in a different size. (I know that when we've got a lot of freespace (delete a lot of rows) in a partition, a rebuild results in a smaller .ibd file.)

Comment: ... I'm not saying a REBUILD will result in a smaller file... I'm curious if it does. A smaller file would indicate there was some free space in the existing partition.

Comment: I would doublecheck if the old table was DYNAMIC or COMPACT. That could also make a difference, depending on the 'additional columns' column types.

Comment: Will you be "purging" old data now that you are partitioned on `action_date`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark this question as answered, but I can report that the Alter Table <name> Rebuild Partition did work in creating a smaller file.  It did not return the table to its original size, but it did result in about a 40% reduction in the table size.  Apologies for the long delay in responding.  It took a while to find a weekend when I could perform maintenance on the table...

Answer (score 0):

> adding new fields essentially requires a rebuild anyway, so why not

I predict you will regret it.

> The existing table was approximately 430 GB.

According to size of .ibd?  Or `SHOW TABLE STATUS`?  Or the dump size, which would be bogus (see below).

> it is significantly more than the text dump file

The lengths in `TABLE STATUS` include several flavors of overhead (BTree, free space, extra extents, etc), plus the indexes (which are not in the dump file).

Also, think about a `BIGINT` that contains 1234.  The .ibd will 8 bytes plus some overhead; the dump will have 5 ('1234', plus a comma).  That leads to my next point...

Are there really more than 4 *billion* merchants?  `merchant_id` is `BIGINT` (8 bytes); `INT UNSIGNED` is only 4 bytes and allows 0..4 billion.

What's in `uid`?  If it is some sort of UUID, it seems awfully long.

Do you happen to have the "stats from I_S.TABLES" from the old table?

So far, I have not addressed "whether the repartioning explains the roughly doubled size".

> extra columns (2 Bigint, 2 Varchar(200), 1 Date)

That's *about* 29 bytes per row (15GB of Data_length), perhaps less since they are `NULL`.

You seem to be using the default `ROW_FORMAT`.  I suspect this did not change in the conversion.

It is usually unwise to *start* an index with the "partition key" (`merchant_id` or `action_date`).  This is because you are already "pruning" on that key; you are better off starting the index with something else.  (Caveat:  There are exceptions.)

Check the `CHARACTER SET` and datatype of the "additional columns".  If something changed, that could be significant.

> would I end up with a table more like the size of my original table ~430 GB?

Alas, until we figure out why it grew, I can't answer that question.

> I'm more interested in whether random insertion vs. the partition (ACTION_DATE) would lead to wasted space / half empty pages.

I recommend you try the following experiment.  Do *not* use optimize partition; see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42822 .  Instead do this to defragment *one* partition (such as p02):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name REBUILD PARTITION p02;
```

You could do this `SELECT` before and after in order to see the change(s) to the `PARTITIONs`:

```
SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.PARTITIONS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'        -- change as needed
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'      -- change as needed
    ORDER BY PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION,
          SUBPARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

It's a generic query to get the table-status-like info for the partitions of one table.

If the `REBUILD` cuts the partition by about 50%, then we have the answer.

Generally, randomly inserting into a BTree should leave you with about 69% (not 50%) of the "full" size.  Hence, I'm not 'expecting' this to be the solution/answer.

Comment: A few questions for my own clarification: `It is usually unwise to start an index with the "partition key"` - Can you explain? How do you define `partition key`, what do you mean by `start an index`, why is it a bad idea, and what are the exceptions?  Also, the OP is not defining the colums as `UNSIGNED`, I think there in lies a portion of the problem, as a number of the columns are not explicitly labled as such.

Comment: The "partition key" is what you use in `PARTITION BY ...`.  Specifically, `merchant_id` in the old case, and `action_date` in the new.

Comment: As for explaining my "advice"; can you provide a couple of `SELECTs`; perhaps they will lead to a good explanation.  "Start an index" -- Notice how the first column in `KEY oc_rpt_mpad_idx (MERCHANT_ID, PROGRAM_ID, ACTION_DATE, AFFILIATE_ID)` is the partition key.